# Cannot connect to my externally hosted (remote) iPage webserver from home but works from work and mobile devices

Tags: networking, router, internet

I am using an [Inteno DG301B-R1](http://www.intenogroup.com/store/tabid/88/categoryid/3/productid/674/default.aspx) router and I am trying to connect to my externally hosted (remote) webserver from home, but I am unable to access it through my browser. I have not changed any of the default settings. If I try to ping its IP, I won't receive any packets either. If I try it through my mobile network it will work. Same if I try it from work.

I have contacted my ISP, but they claim there is nothing wrong from their part. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I received a new router from my ISP, and I guess the error might have started then, but I have no idea why that would make me unable to access this specific webserver. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my question. I have not changed any settings, and cannot see why port forwarding has anything to do with it, as I am trying to connect to an external IP address from home (not the other way around).

Comment: Yes, more specifically on ipage.

Comment: I can see that a clarifaction helps, but in my defense it is actually a dedicated webserver. Anyway, I am completely unable to see why I cannot access it from my home LAN. In my mind it has to be either router or ISP, but any suggestions/ideas helps.

Comment: I'm getting a "This webpage is not available" with errorcode "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". When I try to ping from my own computer, it seems like the IP is alive, but I am not receiving any packets. Everything seems OK from those tools as well. I think we can conclude that everything from ipage's part seems to be OK. The fact that I can access it from elsewhere also proves that, if not my IP could be blocked from their part (will check into that).